# WP7 - Using RX, Subscribe only triggering once but OnNext() always triggering?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system.reactive

Ok im having another play with reactive extentions, specifically with wp7.

I'm looking at the GeoCoordinateWatcher positon changed event like so

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<GeoCoordinate>(GeoCoordinate.Unknown);
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default) { MovementThreshold = 0 };

watcher.PositionChanged += (o, args) =>
{
   var newLocation = args.Position.Location;

   if ((DateTime.Now - args.Position.Timestamp.DateTime) < locationTimeout)
   {
        subject.OnNext(newLocation);
    }
};
```

I am subscribing like so

```
MyLocation.StartGettingLocations()
 .Subscribe(pos =>
 {
       // Do something with the position
       PlotLine.Locations.Add(pos);
       bingMap.SetView(pos, 15);
 });
```

The app runs but the problem is the code in side the Subscribe only happens once yet if I put a break point in the subject.OnNext(newLocation), I see its constantly getting triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]

Ok I can see what was wrong, the code (which is not mine im just learning from it), uses DistinctUntilChanged(). I am assuming, from briefly reading, that this stops the same value pumping out to the subscriber? so interms of what I was using it for, location tracking, if the phone was in the same position and the GeoCoordinate was unchanged then it would be pointless sending it to the subscriber so it just prevents it?

Comment: Some context about how these two code snippets relate would help.  Is the first snippet the MyLocation.StartGettingLocations referenced in the second?

Comment: Sorry about that, something I quickly put up before I left work. If you can see from the EDIT I know the problem just need to understand it.

Comment: @Gaz98: you are correct. It will not push a new value to an observer unless the value has changed. Removing the .DistinctUntilChanged() behavior will cause same values to be pushed to observers.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the question has been answered in the comments (ie remove `DistinctUntilChanged` if you want locations even though the user isn't moving). However, there was something bothering about this question - it's using Rx, but not particularly effectively.

First, there's a much simpler way to turn the events into observables (which in turns makes them simpler to work with):

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default) { MovementThreshold = 0 };  
var geo = Observable.FromEventPattern<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(
                               ev => watcher.PositionChanged += ev, 
                               ev => watcher.PositionChanged -= ev)
                    .Select(ev => ev.EventArgs.Position);
```

Then, to get the changes, no need for that imperative bit of code. Just do this:

```
var changes = geo.Where(pos => (DateTime.Now - pos.Timestamp.DateTime) < locationTimeout)
                 .Select(pos => pos.Location)
                 .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

(You can remove the `DistinctUntilChanged` of course, that wasn't in your posted code).

Now you can work with `changes` directly:

```
changes.Subscribe(loc =>
{
   PlotLine.Locations.Add(pos);
   bingMap.SetView(pos, 15);
});
```

There's no need to manage a subject that is really just shadowing a set of events. Just turns the events into Observables. Then because you're using Observables all the way through, you have access to a number of combinators that will allow you to do a lot more than you currently are.

Comment: wow cheers for that! I will have a go at using this code to see if I follow, thanks again.